# SSL Timeout in Drupal's Akamai Module

Tags: ssl

Had posted this on [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981101/ssl-timeout-in-drupals-akamai-module), but someone suggested I repost here

I have a client using the Drupal Akamai module to manage their site's caching. The client reports the following group of errors happen occasionally when a certain content type is deleted, however, I suspect that it is not limited to a specific content type.

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: connection timeout in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: Failed to enable crypto in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: connect() failed: Unspecified error in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

The referenced line is a call to a method defined in the SoapClient's wsdl

`$response = $ccuapi->purgeRequest($name, $pwd, $network, $opt, $uris);`

I've searched high and low for why this may be happening. Although I've learned a great deal hunting this one down, I'm no soap expert. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

I'm not able to perform extensive testing to try and reproduce the error, but it appears that the urls being sent to akamai are well formed. At one point, an excessive number of redundant requests were being sent, but this was cleared up in a recent release, so that may even have fixed it.