# How to fix SalesForce authentication errors on localhost?

Tags: crm

I am fairly new to developing with Drupal, and new to this forum, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

While trying to authorize SalesForce with a local install I get the following two errors with when going to the oauth_callback.

Note: I have not included the entire path to save space but the reference points are accurate for the doc and line the error references.

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in Salesforce->requestToken() (line 338 of salesforce.inc)
>
> SalesforceException: Error opening socket ssl://login.salesforce.com:443 in Salesforce->requestToken() (line 342 of salesforce.inc)

Local Environment: Mac OS Mavericks with XAMPP 5.6.3, SSL enabled on port 443 in `httpd-vhosts.conf` with certs created using OpenSSL.

Extension: `php_openssl.dll` uncommented in php.ini

Also to note the Drupal install was pulled from a live site that has SF module enabled and working.

I created a new connected app with the proper `oauth_callback` to the local site which is `https://secure.localhost/salesforce/oauth_callback`

I have both HTTPS and HTTP enabled, I have noticed that in the *Status Report* when using HTTPS I do get a HTTP Failure error in the status report.

The request url from salesforce is passing a code EX: `https://secure.localhost/salesforce/oauth_callback?code=aPrxMZkm7lCkgfR3...`

With a Status code of `500 Service unavailable`.

I have looked all over online and on this site, and can't seem to find anything that works. I have tried a few patches to the `common.inc` file, but none of them seemed to work.

Like I said any help would be greatly appreciated, I am just not sure if it is Drupal, Salesforce, or my local setup.

Comment: Have you created an app in Salesforce with URL Callback to your local: `https://secure.localhost/` and you're using the right auth keys of that app?

Comment: Are you trying to use live Salesforce or sandbox? It seems you're trying to use live. So if you're trying to use sandbox, your endpoints are wrong.

Comment: Do you still get 'HTTP Failure error' in the Status Report, or you're talking about the past?

Comment: Kenorb, thank you for your replies: Yes I have the right auth keys, I am using a live site in salesforce not sandbox, I created a second connected app for my local site and am using an endpoint that links to my local site. And yes I still get the http failure error in the status report.

Comment: Are you using Secure Site or Secure Pages? If yes, disable them to see if that helps. If you go to `https://secure.localhost/salesforce/oauth_callback` (without any query), what page do you get (or which error)?

Comment: I am using neither Secure Site or Secure Pages just setup https via apache configurations. When I go to the oauth_callback url you posted above, I get access denied, I get this also when I am logged in.

Comment: Your problem is when salesforce module is requesting authorization token from Salesforce and it fails when doing httpRequest. `500` is coming from Salesforce, so I think you should check why it can't connect to it and fix your HTTP Failure error (try disabling firewall and anti-virus if any). Then check if  you're not overriding any curl settings (e.g. `~/.curlrc`) or you're not behind the proxy. Please also add `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` to your setting file (if you don't have it). Check if `curl login.salesforce.com:443` shell command doesn't give you any errors.

Comment: Kenorb, thank you again for helping me troubleshoot this. I do have $conf['https'] = TRUE; in settings file, no antivirus or firewall, curl does not give me any errors when I login into salesforce, and from what I can tell nothing is being overwritten. I will continue to try to figure out the HTTP failure error, but have yet to find any answers after hours of searching.

Comment: Can you also check if your PHP is not in Safe mode, and you didn't [disabled PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) (such as `stream_socket_client`).

Answer (score 3):

In general, to make SalesForce authentication to work on localhost, you need to:

- Create an app in Salesforce with URL Callback to your local (`https://localhost/salesforce/oauth_callback`) with appropriate permissions.

  > In Salesforce go to Your Name > Setup > Create > Apps then create a new Connected App. (Depending on your Salesforce instance, you may need to go to Your Name > Setup > Develop > Remote Access.)
- Your site needs to be SSL enabled to authorize the remote application using OAUTH.
- If using the SOAP API, PHP must be compiled with [SOAP web services](http://php.net/soap) and [OpenSSL support](http://php.net/openssl).
- Use the right auth *key* and *secret* to Authorize your app (Configuration » Salesforce).
- Make sure you're connecting to the right endpoints (live or sandbox).
- For more help, check *Help » Salesforce API* in Drupal, or [SalesForce documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/quickstart_oauth.htm).
- Add `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` to your setting file.

The error in `Salesforce->requestToken()` indicates that there is a problem exchanging an authorization code for an access token.

Further more, the error:

> Error opening socket ssl://login.salesforce.com:443 in Salesforce->requestToken()

indicates the problem connecting to Salesforce endpoint it-self (check `requestToken()` in `includes/salesforce.inc` for more details).

To diagnose the problem, please check *Reports » Status report* if you've got *HTTP Failure error* and that your localhost can connect to Salesforce end point via curl:

```
$ curl login.salesforce.com:443
```

If your `curl` is connecting fine and you've still *HTTP Failure error* in your *Status report*, then try to:

- Temporary disable Secure Site or Secure Pages modules if present.
- Make sure you've firewall (e.g. `iptables`) and antivirus is switched off (for testing purposes).
- Make sure you're not behind the proxy.
- Make sure you're not running LAMP in a chroot/jail/VM environment.
- Make sure you some network functions aren't [disabled PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) (e.g. `stream_socket_client`).
- Make sure your PHP is not in [Safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) (`safe_mode = On`) by:

  ```
  php -r "var_dump(ini_get('safe_mode'));"
  ```
- Double check your `/etc/hosts` or `~/.curlrc` doesn't have anything suspicious (you can add `insecure` to your `.curlrc` for testing purposes).
- Check is there is no any problem with certificates (e.g. your system date is incorrect, you added the certificate and your [PHP openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) sees your certificates correctly).

  In PHP 5.6 you can [specify *openssl.cafile* and *openssl.capath*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298282/php-and-ssl-ca-verification-os-independent),

  e.g. `openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`

If none of above work, please check below simple PHP script which can check if your PHP can connect to external host:

```
<?php
fsockopen('ssl://login.salesforce.com',443,$errno,$errstr) ? print("UP") : print("DOWN:".$errstr);
?>
```

Save it to the file (`test.php`) and place it inside your web root and open via web browser.

If it fails, it's either problem with your PHP configuration or your network. You can debug it further more by using system call tracer (debugger) as below (install it if required):

```
$ strace -f -e network php test.php # For Linux
$ truss -f php test.php # For BSD
$ sudo dtruss php test.php # For OSX
# For Windows, you may look for StraceNT.
```

Then you've to analyse the log for any issues.

Or the following [perl script](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1118455):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Mozilla::CA;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
        ssl_opts => {
                verify_hostname => 1,
                SSL_ca_file => Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file()
        }) or die;
my $url = $ARGV[0] || 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
my $res = $ua->get($url);
print $res->code . "\n";

exit;
```

See also:

- [Using cURL in PHP to access HTTPS (SSL/TLS) protected sites.](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)
- [SSL Certificate Verification](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)
- [Using Curl to login to Salesforce API](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008ngRIAQ) at Salesforce Developers
- [token failed with status 0!](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099wwIAA) at Salesforce Developers
- [How to fix Curl Error Ssl Certificate Problem Verify That The Ca Error?](http://erasesoftware.com/curl-error-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca/)

Comment: Kenorb, thank you. The php fsockopen does fail, so I will try to determine why. I have gone through the check list you provided and so far nothing is setup that would mess up the connection, or at least not based on the list provided above under "If your curl is connecting fine and you've HTTP Failure error, then:" I will continue to troubleshoot

Comment: @jtrenton Added additional info how to debug `fsockopen()` further more.

Comment: Here are the errors I get back FYI:                    Warning: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysites/huawei/web/test.php on line 2

Warning: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysites/huawei/web/test.php on line 2

Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://login.salesforce.com:443 (Unknown error) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysites/huawei/web/test.php on line 2
DOWN:

Comment: @jtrenton So it's a problem with the certificate, verify that your system date is correct and try adding `insecure` to your `~/.curlrc`. Otherwise try google it.

Comment: Kenorb, thank you again for your continued help. I have tried googling, alot, but still can't determine the issue. If I have set the paths to the certificates in my httpd-ssl.conf & httpd-vhost.conf are those the certs that would be getting picked up? Or does Openssl use a different path when using fsockopen? I also ran sudo dtruss php test.php but to be honest I was not sure what I needed to look for.

Comment: @jtrenton Your main error that you should google for is 'Failed to enable crypto' or 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', one is suggesting to [enable SSL3 as described on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078182/openssl-file-get-contents-failed-to-enable-crypto) or [to accept that certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok), so you may try to ask another question, as it's specific error about certificate, similar to [this one](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/48404/1908).

Comment: So I have googled till my fingers bleed, and still keep getting errors. One thing did which may be part of the problem is I created another php test page and put the following into it: <?php print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations()); ?> The info it returns points to the generic openssl directories and not any actual certs. Could this be part of the problem? Do I have to adjust the openssl.cnf file in order for this to work?

Comment: Also is there a conflict with my Mac Openssl and the Openssl provided by XAMPP? I have changed the openssl.cnf file but the paths stay the same.

Comment: @jtrenton Added few links which can be useful. Try somehow to force curl to use `insecure` flag, this could solve the problem I think. Or add this certificate to your system somehow to be permanently accepted.

Comment: Kenorb thank you again for all of your help. I finally managed to fix it by adding the following to my php.ini file openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem